# How to export a List with the values separated by a simple empty space?

Tags: export, output-formatting

I have this: `list=Range[1,4]` and I want to `Export` the values in a text-file. But the values should be separated by a single empty space, like this:

> in MMA[ {1,2,3,4} ] -> in txt-file[ 1 2 3 4 ]

How do I get extended control over the export options?
Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consult the [`ref/format/Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) section of the documentation.

Using `"Table"` as the export format and specifying the option `"FieldSeparators" -> " "` you can get what you want:

```
ExportString[{Range[4]}, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "]
(* 1 2 3 4 *)
```

Note that I've wrapped `Range[]` in a list like `{Range[4]}`, since each element at the top level is expected to be a row.

To have a more general control over the import and export options you can also try spelunking:

```
<<GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[Export]
```

After some searching there I found a function called `` System`Convert`TableDump`ExportTable `` which admits the options

```
"LineSeparators"
"FieldSeparators"
"TextDelimiters"
"TableHeadings"
CharacterEncoding
Alignment
```

You can either search around in this way if the documentation doesn't provide enough information or just roll your own export routine with the help of functions such as `OpenWrite` and others, when the built-in functionality isn't enough.